# Plotting the output of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I have solved two differential equations $x[z,t]$ and $w[z,t]$ numerically. Their solutions are stored in the notebook inside variables $sol$ and $sol1$ respectively. The solutions have both imaginary and real parts. I want a parametric plot which involves real and imaginary parts of both the solutions. The code is provided below:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{2 (Re[w[z, 1]] Re[x[z, 1]] + 
 Im[x[z, 1]] Im[w[z, 1]])/((Re[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[
   x[z, 1]])^2 + (Re[w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[w[z, 1]])^2) /. {sol1, 
sol}, 2 (
Re[w[z, 1]] Im[x[z, 1]] + 
 Im[w[z, 1]] Re[x[z, 1]])/((Re[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[
   x[z, 1]])^2 + (Re[w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[w[z, 1]])^2) /. {sol1, 
sol}, ((Re[w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[w[z, 1]])^2 - (Re[x[z, 1]])^2 - (Im[
  x[z, 1]])^2)/((Re[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Re[
  w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[w[z, 1]])^2) /. {sol1, sol}}, {z, -20, 20}]
```

No graph is shown in the output. I can not figure out the error in the code.

**Edit:** $x[z,t]$ and $w[z,t]$ have the following codes:

```
ode = I*D[x[z, t], t] == -1/2*D[x[z, t], {z, 2}] + 3*z*x[z, t]
ic = x[z, 0] == Exp[-z^2]/(Pi)^(1/4)
bc = {x[-20, t] == 0, x[20, t] == 0}
sol = NDSolve[{ode, ic, bc}, x, {t, 0, 1}, {z, -20, 20}, 
  MaxStepSize -> 0.01]

ode = I*D[w[z, t], t] == -1/2*D[w[z, t], {z, 2}] - 3*z*w[z, t]
ic = w[z, 0] == Exp[-z^2]/(Pi)^(1/4)
bc = {w[-20, t] == 0, w[20, t] == 0}
sol1 = NDSolve[{ode, ic, bc}, w, {t, 0, 1}, {z, -20, 20}, 
  MaxStepSize -> 0.01]
```

Comment: A trick I've found helpful many times. When any kind of plot isn't working I replace plot with `Table` and look at the result. Almost always I can immediately see the problem. Sometimes it takes a little more thinking to understand why I have that problem, but I am much closer than I am sitting there wondering why is my plot blank. I would have done that for you but I don't have your x and w

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D` has the attribute `HoldAll`. Use `Evaluate`, e.g., `ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{2 (Re[w[z, 1]] Re[x[z, 1]] + Im[x[z, 1]] Im[w[z, 1]])/((Re[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Re[w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[w[z, 1]])^2), 2 (Re[w[z, 1]] Im[x[z, 1]] + Im[w[z, 1]] Re[x[z, 1]])/((Re[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Re[w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[w[z, 1]])^2), ((Re[w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[w[z, 1]])^2 - (Re[x[z, 1]])^2 - (Im[x[z, 1]])^2)/((Re[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Re[w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[w[z, 1]])^2)} /. {sol1, sol}], {z, -20, 20}]`

Comment: @Bill I have now provided that in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
rsol = Flatten[{sol, sol1}];

g[z_] = {2 (Re[w[z, 1]] Re[x[z, 1]] + 
        Im[x[z, 1]] Im[
          w[z, 1]])/((Re[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Re[
           w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[w[z, 1]])^2), 
    2 (Re[w[z, 1]] Im[x[z, 1]] + 
        Im[w[z, 1]] Re[
          x[z, 1]])/((Re[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Re[
           w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[w[z, 1]])^2), ((Re[w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[
          w[z, 1]])^2 - (Re[x[z, 1]])^2 - (Im[x[z, 1]])^2)/((Re[
          x[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[x[z, 1]])^2 + (Re[w[z, 1]])^2 + (Im[
          w[z, 1]])^2)} /. rsol;

ParametricPlot3D[g[z], {z, -20, 20}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]